# Using command results as Var (Shell)

Tags: shell

Why something as simple as this won't work?
echo "hola" works but it never show "1 es igual a 1" what is wrong with it? Im very new at this sorry 4 the english!

```
#!/bin/tcsh
VAR=`grep 'hola' AL24CL.log`
echo $VAR
VAR2='hola'
if [ '$VAR' = '$VAR2' ];
then
echo "1 es igual a 1"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did! But nothing, if i change the first VAR for simply "hola" it works but idk why wouldn´t work that command line the echo $VAR works perfectly fine and it finds it on the AL24CL.log!

Comment: `grep` prints whole lines that contain the pattern. Not just the matched pattern. Add `-o` to print only the matched part. Also if there are several matches, you'll have multiple lines printed. Add `-m1` to avoid that.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer i'll try that! i have to go to work!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `VAR` value is correct, the comparison never matches because single quotes (`'`) prevents variables expansion, so you are comparing two strings literals. Try using double quotes (`"`) where expansion is needed i.e. replace

```
if [ '$VAR' = '$VAR2' ];
```

with

```
if [ "$VAR" = "$VAR2" ];
```

Comment: Hi! i did! but nothing changes only works when i change the `grep 'hola' AL24CL.log` var for VAR="hola" then it works properly and yo can see "1 es igual a 1" but i need the grep line to search for "hola" (a string) inside AL24CL.log

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem, thanks to everyone who've answered the question!

```
VAR=`grep ">>> Total: 0 Alarms (0 Critical, 0 Major)" AL24CL.log`
VAR2="$VAR"
if [ "$VAR2" = ">>> Total: 0 Alarms (0 Critical, 0 Major)" ];
    then
    echo "NO TIENE ALARMAS"
    tail +55 AL24CL.log
else
    echo "Tiene alarmas"
fi
```